# Conversion problem

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

I'm using gcc 4.3.2.

I have the following code (simplified):

```
#include <cstdlib>

template<int SIZE>
class Buffer
{
public:
    explicit Buffer(const char *p = NULL) {}
    explicit Buffer(const Buffer &other);

    const char *c_str() const { return m_buffer; }

private:
    char m_buffer[SIZE];
};

typedef Buffer<10> A;
typedef Buffer<20> B;

void Foo(A a) {
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    Foo(b.c_str());  // line 25 fails compilation
    return 1;
}
```

Compilation yields:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:25: error: conversion from ‘const char*’ to non-scalar type ‘A’ requested
```

But there's c-tor receiving const char *.

UDP:

If I remove explicit from 1st c-tor I receive

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘Buffer<10>::Buffer(A)’
test.cpp:7: note: candidates are: Buffer<SIZE>::Buffer(const char*) [with int SIZE = 10]
test.cpp:25: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void Foo(A)’
```

If I use Foo(A(b.c_str())) I receive:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘Buffer<10>::Buffer(A)’
test.cpp:25: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void Foo(A)’
```

Comment: I posted a similar question but in a simpler striiped down case with the same problem ion which there isn't the 'explicit' distraction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735107/how-do-i-fix-a-const-char-constructor-conversion-chain-error-in-gcc-compile

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your conversion constructor is declared `explicit`. Keyword `explicit` is specifically intended to prevent implicit conversions by that constructor. And an implicit conversion is exactly what you expect to happen in your code (at the `Foo` call).

Why did you declare your constructor `explicit`, if you want it to work in implicit conversions?

Comment: When B is called A type should be constructed from b.c_str(), which is const char *. A's 1st c-tor receives const char *, so explicit should not be  a problem here. Do I miss something?

Comment: Yes. `explicit` means the compiler *will not* do exactly that. If you remove explicit, it will be able to *implicitly* do the conversion.

Comment: @idimba: You are passing a `const char*` to a function that expects `A`. `const char*` is not `A`, so a conversion is required. But the compiler cannot use `A::A(const char *)` conversion constructor, because it is declared `explicit`. If you want this constructor to be used, you have to spell out an explicit conversion `Foo(A(b.c_str()))`

Comment: @idimba, Wait - the buffer also has an explicit size. Not sure about null termination anymore now. Sure you didn't want to say `Foo(A(b.c_str()));` ? If you make it implicit, you would also succeed with `Foo("bar");` which seems all wrong.

Comment: As you see from UDP Foo(A(b.c_str())) doesn't help ...:(

Comment: I'm afraid that it doesn't help because your copy-constructor is also declared `explicit`, so all your attempts to pass `A` by value will fail. Stop abusing `explicit` :)

Comment: I looked up into the Standard again and caught GCC doing the wrong thing (comeau compiles his code with only the first one being implicit) when only the first is implicit: `Foo(b.c_str());` should work fine, but `Foo(A(b.c_str()));` should fail according to the Standard. But GCC fails for both. This is counterintuitive, though, i think. Anyway, make those explicits go away xD

Answer (score 3):

A and B are totally different types. As Andrey pointed out, there is no implicit callable constructor for conversion. You'll have to write

```
Foo(A(b.c_str()));
```

This will create a temporary 'automatic' (unnamed) object of type A using the explicit constructor for const char. And this will be passed to Foo.

Comment: Or remove `explicit`, I would add.